# Prove that the limit does not exist: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,3)}\frac{|\sin(3x-y)|}{\sqrt{2(x-1)^2+5(y-3)^4}}$ (Without L'Hopital's)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

It seems that the function is underfined at $(1,3)$, so when I try to directly plug in $(1,3)$ via limit laws, I get an undetermined term $\frac{0}{0}$. So I tried instead to consider individual paths in the domain leading towards $(1,3)$, i.e.,

Along the x-axis: fixing $y=0$, $$f(x,0)=\frac{|\sin(3x)|}{\sqrt{2(x-1)^2+5(y-3)^4}}$$

However, I don't see where to go from there (if this is even the right approach), and try to show that two different paths that I pick result in differing limits.

For these type of questions in general, am I supposed to simply "try" a bunch of paths towards my limit point $(a,b)$ and simply "hope" that two paths will give different limits, or can we do better with a faster method?

Comment: You should try along $y=3, x=1$

Comment: You can try the horizontal case $(x,3)$ and the vertical case $(1, y)$ and hope the results are different. A stronger method is to take $x = 1 + \epsilon \cos(\phi)$ and $y = 3 + \epsilon \sin(\phi)$. Substitute this and check whether the result depends on $\phi$.

Comment: First reduce to $(u,v)\to(0,0)$ by letting $x=1+u,y=3+v.$ Then, the first paths to try are the linear ones, $v=ku.$ If your limit depends on $k,$ you have won. Else, try more "ad hoc" paths.

Comment: 1) You have not replaced $y$ with zero under the radical in denominator. 2) You will not approach point $(1,3)$ by walking along the $X$ axis only $(y=0)$.

Comment: Ok, I tried the general linear path approach, but still cannot get it to work after several attempts: 

Let x=1+u and y=3+u, so u=x-1 and v=y-3
then $$\lim{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\frac{|\sin(3u-v)|}{\sqrt{2u^2+5v^4}}$$ 
now consider the limit along a generic linear path $v=mu, ; m\in\mathbb{R}$ 
so we have: 
$f(u,mu)=\frac{|\sin(3u-mu)|}{\sqrt{2u^2+5(mu)^4}}=\frac{|\sin(u(3-m))|}{u \sqrt{2+5m^4u^2}}$.
I planned on choosing different values of m to find two that contradict, but then I realised that I am still going to get an indeterminate form no matter what m I choose: 0/0

Comment: I think I finally managed to get it using @AnneBauval 's method (or at least what I think you meant). Continuing with what I had above, I get $$\lim_{u\to 0} \left[ \frac{|\sin((3-m)u)|}{|u|}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+5m^4u^2}}\right ]$$. Then by limit laws $$\lim{u\to 0} \left[ \frac{|\sin((3-m)u)|}{|u|}\right ] \cdot \lim{u\to 0} \left [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+5m^4u^2}}\right ]\implies |3-m|\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},$$ and since $v=mu$ was an arbitrary linear path through $(0,0)$, we can clearly choose two different $m$ that give different limits. Can someone please confirm? This is quite new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the paths $y=mx+3-m$ for $m\in\Bbb R^+$ passing through the point $(1,3)$. Along these paths, the given limit becomes
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,3)}\frac{|\sin(3x-y)|}{\sqrt{2(x-1)^2+5(y-3)^4}}=\lim_{x\to 1}\left|\frac{\sin((m-3)(x-1))|}{x-1}\right|\frac1{\sqrt{2+5m^4(x-1)^2}}$$
which is equal to $\frac{|m-3|}{\sqrt2}.$ It depends on $m$. So, there is no limit. Note that the trigonometric limit is well-known and it can be calculated without L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

First reduce to $(u,v)→(0,0)$
by letting $x=1+u,y=3+v.$
Then, the first paths to try are the linear ones, $v=mu.$
[If your limit depends on $m,$
you have won](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950934). Else, try more "ad hoc" paths.

Your last comment confirms that you completely understood: as $u\to0,$
$$\begin{align}\frac{|\sin(3x-y)|}{\sqrt{2(x-1)^2+5(y-3)^4}}&=\frac{|\sin(3u-v)|}{\sqrt{2u^2+5v^4}}\\&=\frac{|\sin((3-m)u)|}{\sqrt{2u^2+5m^2u^4}}\\&\sim\frac{|3-m||u|}{|u|\sqrt{2+5m^2u^2}}\\&\to\frac{|3-m|}{\sqrt2}\end{align}$$
which depends on $m,$ thereby proving that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,3)}\frac{|\sin(3x-y)|}{\sqrt{2(x-1)^2+5(y-3)^4}}$ does not exist.

You might also notice that the limit along the line $u=0$ (as $v\to0$) is $+\infty.$